# Monitoring RAW disk activity

Tags: .net, hard-drive, low-level

Is there a way to monitor what exactly hard drive does while doing certain high-level operations such as

```
Directory.CreateDirectory()

File.Exists()
```

etc.

I am talking about .NET programming, and as a result I would like to see something like:

```
seek to cylinder xx sector yy
read xx clusters
seek to ...
```

It would be great if all of these would be measured with timings, and so on.

Any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

You could pull in the S.M.A.R.T data and map it by time each seek and read operation has a counter in hardware.

If the drive supports it.